# Need help/advice on how to test an ostream passed to a function

Tags: c++, testing

I have a function that gets an ostream passed to it. I need to test the ostream to make sure it will work. I put the print statement in a try block with a catch statement to catch all exceptions. Now to test if this will work, i need a little help creating a bad ostream to pass the function.

I tried this:

```
filebuf buffer;
ostream& out = ostream(&buffer);
test1.print(out);
```

But when i test it, i cannot get my error message to be printed. What would be a better way to create a bad ostream to be passed to the function.

Also, is there a better way to check the ostream than using a try-catch block?

Comment: Check for what? Define "bad". What sort of error message?

Comment: ostream.bad() will tell you the state of the stream

Comment: `bad` doesn't check the failbit, so it's not often useful.

Comment: @DFord: If you got your answer (either mine or Steve's) then you should _accept_ it. Otherwise, never mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about an `ofstream` that's not open to any file?

Comment: @iammilind: it answers, "What would be a better way to create a bad ostream to be passed to the function". Personally I didn't consider that to be the most urgent part of the question :-)

Comment: @Steve: The only other part of the question is an "also" addendum in the very last line, which I chose to ignore.

Comment: @Tomalak: that and the title ;-)

Comment: fwiw, I assumed that the questioner meant "better" in the sense of "will actually trigger my test code", so I felt it necessary to point out that the problem wasn't the stream. I don't think this deserves -1, though, it is a more concise way to get a stream that "doesn't work", as requested.

Comment: @Steve: The title _describes_ the question. The question itself is in the body. :)

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use ostream.

Comment: @DFord: `ofstream` *is* an `ostream`, it's a subclass. And streams are suitably polymorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Streams don't in general throw exceptions when they don't work, so I would not expect your error message to be printed whether your operation succeeded or not.

The `ios` base class has a function called `exceptions` that can be used to control that, but it's fairly anti-social to write a function that changes the state of an argument like that, so you might have to be sure to restore it (even if it throws an exception...)

The usual way to test success of an operation on a stream is using `if`. A stream evaluates to a true value if everything is OK, a false value otherwise - by which I mean a value that's true/false as far as conditionals are concerned, not the `bool` values `true` or `false`.

To be precise, it's false if the failbit or badbit is set. The last operation "didn't work" if and only if at least one of those is set.

Comment: + imaginary 0.5 points, when combined with Tomalak's answer - then we have a full answer! :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried checking the failbit after the attempted output and that triggered my error message